# Parent-child dimension in Analysis Services from Server2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, olap

Someone know some interesting and complete tutorial about how to create a Parent-Child dimension in Server2008?
I found a brief introduction in Server2005, but a lot of step are changed.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, it changed (whether it is better is debatable) but I found this blog very useful.

http://www.brustblog.com/archive/2008/06/22/analysis-services-2008-wizards-is-the-magic-gone.aspx

Good luck!